# Error importing shapefile to database even if the connection is successful

Tags: qgis

Recently I have installed shapefile import export plugin in pgadmin3. I need to import shapefile in my database but I can't. Connection to database was also successful but unfortunately the error message is as follows:

[image: PostGIS error message]

Comment: Please always include error messages as text in preference to as pictures only, that way they can be searched for by anyone experiencing the same thing later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to create `Postgis` extension. 
First run following query. 
`CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS`
and try to import your shapfile.